# Functor for find_if and map, avoid copy of value

Tags: c++

Is there a way to avoid the copy (I guess that's what's going on under the hood) for the value in the `std::pair` for the functor with a `std::map`?

```
struct request_number_find
{
  request_number_find(const unsigned __int64 &baseline) : _baseline(baseline) {}
  bool operator() (const std::pair<guid, RadioTransmitterInformation> &arg)
//-------------------------------------- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  { 
    return _baseline == arg.second.mPropagationServer.mRequestNumber; 
  }
  unsigned __int64 _baseline;
};
```

Even with C++11 lambda

```
auto it = std::find_if(mRTMap.begin(), mRTMap.end(), 
  [](const std::pair<guid, RadioTransmitterInformation> &t) -> bool { 
    return t.second.mPropagationServer.mRequestNumber == 24031;
  }
);
```

In both cases, I always see the destructor of `RadioTransmitterInformation` getting call multiple times while searching for the value.

Map declaration:

```
std::map<guid, RadioTransmitterInformation, guid_compare> mRTMap;
```

guid_compare:

```
struct guid_compare {
  bool operator() (const guid& lhs, const guid& rhs) const{
    return lhs < rhs;
  }
};
```

Find_if call:

```
std::find_if(mRTMap.begin(), mRTMap.end(), request_number_find(24031));
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> const std::pair<guid, RadioTransmitterInformation> &t
> ```

The value_type of a `map` always stores the key as `const`. But your `pair` here doesn't store the key as `const`. So to call your function, it has to copy the internal `pair` value into a temporary, which gets bound to a `const&` parameter. And thus, gets deleted after calling your lambda.

Instead, use:

```
const std::pair<const guid, RadioTransmitterInformation> &t
```

Or even better:

```
const decltype(mRTMap)::value_type &t
```

Or even better-er if you have C++14:

```
const auto &t
```

Comment: What about with the `decltype` version? Is your map actually a `map<guid, RadioTransmitterInformation>`? You didn't post an [mcve], so I can't be sure.

Comment: Damn nevermind, I made a huge mistake. Your answer did fix my issue. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

If a map has type `std::map<guid, RadioTransmitterInformation>`, then it stores values of type `std::pair<const guid, RadioTransmitterInformation>` - note the `const`.

Since `std::pair<guid, RadioTransmitterInformation>` is a different type, the compiler has to generate a temporary `pair` to call your functors (in either version).

So try using `const std::pair<const guid, RadioTransmitterInformation>&` arguments, or maybe `const decltype(mRTMap)::value_type&`.